# Why is my function to filter files by User ID not filtering any files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, file

I am trying to display files from database only from a certain user and I am kinda stuck how to filter files from database. The View is fine, but if I bind `Viewbag` with `string[] files` variable it display all of them.

```cs
public ActionResult DownloadPDF(string id)
{
    var fileID = (from c in db.Files where c.UserID == id select c);

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/FilesDB/PDF"));
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {            
        files[i] = Path.GetFileName(files[i]);
    }

    var specificFile = files.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Equals(fileID));

    ViewBag.Files = specificFile;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: `var fileID = (from c in db.Files where c.UserID == id select c);` - this is selecting the whole file, not just fileID?

Comment: yea whole file, but that is selecting well, I just found out how to download the file, but its not displaying the view its just download when I trigger actionlink to the view.

Comment: ah I figured out why you asked, I tried before to select by ID and I forgot the variable name like that, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the call `files.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Equals(fileID))`:

- **`files`** is of type `string[]`,
- That makes every **`x`** a `string`,
- **`fileID`** is the result of a Linq query, like `IQueryable<SomeType>`. So not even a single SomeType object, but an object that can return a collection of SomeType objects.
- With **`x`** and **`fileID`** being of totally different types, there is no way that `x.Equals(fileID)` will ever be true.

It might start to work if you can change fileID to be a single string by changing the Linq query to something like this:

```
string fileID = (
    from   c in db.Files
    where  c.UserID == id
    select c.FileID.ToString()
    ).FirstOrDefault();
```